# Writing xarray list-type attributes to netCDF

Tags: python, python-xarray

I wish to have a list of strings as an attribute in an xarray `Dataset` that survives serialization to netCDF. I believe this is possible with the [NC_STRING type](https://www.unidata.ucar.edu/software/netcdf/netcdf-4/newdocs/netcdf-c/Arrays-of-Strings.html) in netCDF-4. xarray supports this but I can't get it to persist after writing to and reading from a netCDF file. After the roundtrip, the attr comes back with the list elements concatenated. I'm thinking I might have to set an encoding parameter, and although I know how to do this for variables, I don't know how for attributes.

```
import xarray as xr
ds = xr.Dataset()
ds.attrs['testing'] = ['a', 'b']
print(ds)
```

Gives:

```
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:  ()
Data variables:
    *empty*
Attributes:
    testing:  ['a', 'b']
```

Now,

```
ds.to_netcdf('asdf.nc')
ds = xr.open_dataset('asdf.nc', autoclose=True)
print(ds)
```

Gives:

```
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:  ()
Data variables:
    *empty*
Attributes:
    testing:  ab
```

### Update

In response to @jhamman's comment, this behavior is supported using netCDF4's `netncattr_string` method:

```
import netCDF4 as nc
rg = nc.Dataset('test_string.nc', 'w', format='NETCDF4')
rg.setncattr_string('testing', ['a', 'b'])
rg.close()
```

Running ncdump on test_string.nc produces:

```
$ ncdump test_string.nc
netcdf test_string {

// global attributes:
        string :testing = "a", "b" ;
}
```

as opposed to setting an attribute in the usual way, which results in a concatenated attribute, as when the nc is created by xarray above:

```
rg = nc.Dataset('test_normal.nc', 'w', format='NETCDF4')
rg.testing = ['a', 'b']
rg.close()
```

ncdump results:

```
$ ncdump test_normal.nc
netcdf test_normal {

// global attributes:
        :testing = "ab" ;
}
```

Reading the .nc file created using `setncattr_string` properly imports a list of strings as the attributes in an xarray Dataset:

```
ds = xr.open_dataset('test_string.nc')
print(ds)
```

gives:

```
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:  ()
Data variables:
    *empty*
Attributes:
    testing:  ['a', 'b']
```

So I guess something like `setncattr_string` could be implemented in xarray to achieve this?

Comment: My initial thought is that this isn't really supported by netcdf/xarray. There really isn't a logical way to store arrays of distinct strings as attributes (it is feasible on variables). What does `ncdump -h asdf.nc` yield?

Comment: @jhamman: I have updated my question to address your comment. In short, I think it's possible using netCDF4, just not using xarray (yet? :-).

Comment: I think this would be worth raising as a feature request with xarray on github. We can probably continue the conversation there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encoding lists of strings as attributes [has been implemented](https://github.com/pydata/xarray/pull/2045) in xarray and should be in the next release (0.10.4).